# Swift only call recursive function X times

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a function I am using to animate 4 `UILabels`. The animation is chained and I am trying to reduce repeated code by creating a recursive function that accepts the label as an argument, on completion calls itself with the next label.

```
   fileprivate func handleAnimations(firstLabel: UILabel, secondLabel: UILabel) -> Void {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 2, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            firstLabel.alpha = 1
        }) { (_) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                secondLabel.alpha = 1
            }) { (_) in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 3, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                    firstLabel.alpha = 0
                    secondLabel.alpha = 0
                }, completion: { (_) in
                    self.handleAnimations(firstLabel: self.introTextLabelThree, secondLabel: self.introTextLabelFour)
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this the best way to achieve this? If so, how I prevent the final complete block calling itself over and over with the final 2 labels?

The effect I am trying to achieve is:

labelOne - fades in

labelTwo - fades in

labelOne and labelTwo - fade out

labelThree - fades in

labelFour - fades in

labelThree and labelFour - fade out

After labelThree and labelFour I would be looking to implement another function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do this. Please use [animateKeyframes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622552-animatekeyframes). This will allow you to properly chain animations without the dreaded pyramid of doom.

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 0, options: [.calculationModeCubic], animations: {
        // Add animations
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 1.0/6.0, animations: {
            self.introTextLabel.alpha = 1
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1.0/6.0, relativeDuration: 1.0/5.0, animations: {
            self.introTextLabelTwo.alpha = 1
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 2.0/6.0, relativeDuration: 1.0/5.0, animations: {
            self.introTextLabel.alpha = 0
            self.introTextLabelTwo.alpha = 0
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 3.0/6.0, relativeDuration: 1.0/5.0, animations: {
            self.introTextLabelThree.alpha = 1
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 4.0/6.0, relativeDuration: 1.0/5.0, animations: {
            self.introTextLabelFour.alpha = 1
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 5.0/6.0, relativeDuration: 1.0/5.0, animations: {
            self.introTextLabelThree.alpha = 0
            self.introTextLabelFour.alpha = 0
        })
    }, completion:{ _ in
        // fire off whatever other method you want here
    })
```